# Cell should never be in update animation (UICollectionView crash)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, crash, uikit

I've got **Cell should never be in update animation** crash in UICollectionView reported by crashlytics
This crash happens only for users on iOS 14. It wasn't noticeable when the application used SDK iOS 13 (it affected less than 0.01 % of all users). But after supporting SDK iOS 14, crash frequency noticeably increased to almost 0.25 % of all users.
Internally UICollectionView, as far as I understand (from some UIKit disassembly journey), loops through visible cells and checks that a cell animation counter is equal to zero (else, it crashes with the following stack trace). It's not for sure, but presumably crash happens while performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)
I couldn't reproduce this bug, and I can't spend more time digging into UIKitCore disassembled code to understand when and why this animation counter changes.

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1915e9114 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1a4e0fcb4 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1914f8308 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource addManagedSourceForIdentifier:user:]
3  Foundation                     0x1927dc2c8 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  UIKitCore                      0x1935b8548 __43-[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:]_block_invoke_4.1070
5  UIKitCore                      0x1935b8000 __43-[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:]_block_invoke.1053
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x191221298 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x191222280 _dispatch_client_callout
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x1911d123c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp
9  CoreFoundation                 0x191568c30 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1915630e8 __CFRunLoopRun
11 CoreFoundation                 0x191562200 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
12 GraphicsServices               0x1a765d598 GSEventRunModal
13 UIKitCore                      0x193e28004 -[UIApplication _run]
14 UIKitCore                      0x193e2d5d8 UIApplicationMain
15 App                            0x100dd2d1c main + 49 (main.m:49)
16 libdyld.dylib                  0x191241598 start
```

Did anyone face the same issue? Were you able to reproduce it?

Comment: I've got the same crash. Same symptoms as yours (numbers skyrocketed on iOS 14). Unfortunately I couldn't repro it still.

Comment: I have observed this crash in tvOS 14. same error message. It happens when deleteItems, reloadItems, insertItems inside performBatchUpdates. Not sure what is the real reason though.

Comment: Yeah, we found that it happens after `updates` and before `completion` call in `performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)`

Comment: I'm seeing this in my app as well. Do you happen to also be using NSFetchedResultsController to update your collection view, @MikhailMaslo?

Comment: @AllenP Hi! No, I'm not using `CoreData`. My app hugely uses `UICollectionView` with it's own diff implementation (there is no other 3rd party involved)

Comment: @MikhailMaslo Are you using TextFields or TextViews inside your collectionView? Any becomeFirstResponder calls at all?

Comment: @YuriReis Hi! I think no, I don't have any textfields or textViews in my collection

Comment: @MikhailMaslo Do you adjust the contentOffset of the collection by any chance? I found this to be one of the causes of the crash, combined with some other reasons (mainly cell constraint animations).

Comment: @YuriReis Sorry for late response. We may have contentOffset adjustment, but we were not able to find connection between this crash and programmatic contentOffset change (though we didn't check this case thoroughly). Also, we noticed that it seems like in iOS 14.2 this issue was resolved (no users were affected on iOS 14.2). So may be we will patiently wait when all users will update to newer iOS versions

Comment: @MikhailMaslo We found that layoutInvalidations + contentOffset changes cause the crash in some instances, but not all of them. Anyway, we are also seeing that on iOS 14.2, no users are affected, so that's good. As the users upgrade, our crash rate is slowly going down.

Comment: We started suddenly started to see this issue with IOS14.3 and 14.5. Did you find a concrete solution/source?

Comment: Unfortunately, no :( But it's not as frequent as it was

Comment: Please I am desperate for a fix is there one?